# Calculate y = x/(1+x^2) on an FPGA

Tags: algorithm, fpga

I need to calculate the function `y=x/(1+x^2)` on a small FPGA in fixed point, can you help me finding the best algorithm?

I thought of those possibilities:

1. as the FPGA is small I think I will use shift&add/subtract algebra a
   multiplier and a divider will use about the same number of cycles,
   right?
2. this function is similar to a digital filter, can I calculate
   divisionless using a feedback loop?
3. I don't think I will have much memory so I'd prefer not using a LUT

Are there other options?
The time requirement isn't very strict so I thought of a simple shift&subtract but if there is something simpler, that might be better.

Comment: What is the range of `x` and how much precision do you need ?

Comment: Why not just calculate 1/x, for x >> 1 there's very little diff.

Comment: I need the full range of x and all the precision I can get, sadly

Comment: That's really too vague as far as requirements are concerned. If you're doing fixed point then you're obviously limited to the number of bits in your fixed point format, so (a) how many bits is that (i.e. what fixed point format are you using ?) and (b) do you need the full precision of your fixed point format, or can you compromise ?

Comment: You're right. I have to do this operation in different formats, at least 1.23 and 1.7 at full precision.

Comment: What FPGA are we talking about? And what do you mean with `1.23`?

Comment: You could consider a CORDIC set up for linear operations. The same hardware could then compute x*z when in rotation mode (minimize z) and -y/x when in vector mode (minimize y). Substitute your variables as necessary for CORDIC x,y,z and fix the sign after the division to get the result.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau: Your idea seems quite efficient as you would be using a single CORDIC for the two parts in two different configurations. But what's the region of convergence for linear cordic? Concerning Point (2) of the question, you could use the difference equation `y_(n+1) = x - y_n * x^2` which can be seen as a "feedback loop". It converges for `|x| < 1` but would require a multiplication.

Comment: Linear CORDIC converges the same as circular for angles (z) between -99.7 and +99.7 degrees. A correction is needed for values outside that range by negating x and y and adding 180 degrees to the angle (flipping the sign bit). That is not a significant increase in hardware required.